# REGXP set of values though GROUP_CONCAT from subquery

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, group-concat

I have this horrible query,

REMOVED

Now this worked perfectly fine when the user only liked one band however this wont work when a user likes 2 or more bands due to subquery returning more than one result however i tried to then `GROUP_CONCAT` i ended up with the `WHERE` clause like below

REMOVED

and this results in the error `#1111 - Invalid use of group function`

if some one would be able to help me do this as i really dont want to have to put the load onto the Apache server pulling the results into php to get values and fire loads of queries off also this could end up being hundreds or possibly thousands of query for one section of a page

**UPDATE 2:**
WooHoo sort of...

```
SELECT 
    B.*,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `blog_likes` AS BL WHERE BL.`blog_id` = B.`blog_id` ) AS likes
FROM blog AS B
WHERE `tags` REGEXP (
    SELECT GOUP_CONCAT(ConcatBandNames, '|') 
    FROM (
        SELECT CONCAT(
            CONCAT(
                '%',
                (
                    SELECT 
                        `band_name` 
                    FROM `band` AS BA 
                    WHERE BA.`band_id` = 
                    ( 
                        SELECT `band_id` 
                        FROM `likes` AS L 
                        WHERE `user_id` = '7' 
                        AND `band_id` = BA.`band_id` 
                    )
                )
            )
            , '%'
        ) AS ConcatBandNames
    ) AS T
)
```

Work's in terms of syntax however now it it's erroring saying `#2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it was supposed to be `GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('.*',CONCAT(band_name, '.*')) SEPARATOR '|')` so my query now looks like

```
SELECT 
    B.*,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `blog_likes` AS BL WHERE BL.`blog_id` = B.`blog_id` ) AS likes
FROM blog AS B
WHERE `tags` REGEXP (
    SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('.*',CONCAT(`band_name`, '.*')) SEPARATOR '|') 
    FROM `band` AS BA 
    WHERE BA.`band_id` = 
    ( 
        SELECT `band_id` 
        FROM `likes` AS L 
        WHERE `user_id` = '7' 
        AND `band_id` = BA.`band_id` 
    )
)
```